# How to Solve $Ax=0$ for System of Lagrangian Derivatives

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to solve a simple quadratic minimisation problem of the form:

$$ min_x\;\;\; \underline{x}^TQ\underline{x} $$
$$ s.t.\quad (\underline{\mu}-r\,\underline{1} )^T\;\underline{x} = 1 $$

Where Q is s.p.d.

Using the method of Lagrange multipliers, I should be able to form:
$$ \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda) = \underline{x}^TQ\underline{x} - \lambda\,\left(\,(\,\underline{\mu}-r\,\underline{1} )^T\,\underline{x} - 1\right)$$

And finding the stationary point:
$$\nabla \mathcal{L} =  2\, Q \,\underline{x} \,- \lambda \,(\underline{\mu}-r\,\underline{1} ) =0$$

If we let $N$ be the length of vector $ \underline{x} $, then this system of equations ($\nabla_{x_1},\, \nabla_{x_2}, \, ..., \nabla_{x_N} , \nabla_\lambda $) can be described in a matrix equation of the form $Ax=b$, which (including the terms for $\nabla_\lambda$) has size N+1, and which can be solved using any typical technique for systems solvers.

However, I find two glaring issues here which suggest I have misunderstood something fundamental.

1. I find (using Python http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/RankNullspace.html) that matrix A (and indeed, also the original $ N\times N$ matrix $Q$) has an empty nullspace. This seems to suggest there is only the trivial solution $\underline{x} = \underline{0}$.
2. If we were to replace the equality constraint with the even simpler:
   $$ s.t.\quad \underline{1}^T \, \underline{x} = 1 $$
   then we find the constraint would evaluate to zero in the Lagrangian derivative, and so would essentially be ignored. This is particularly strange since this constraint should prevent the trivial solution - c.f. $\underline{x}$ being probabilities or allocations which must sum to 1.

What have I got wrong, and how can I solve this minimisation problem using Lagrangian multipliers to solve for Ax=b?

Comment: You are using the wrong right-hand-side; the last element should be 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a linear term in your objective function, so of course you are getting the multidimensional version of $x^2$.  (If you expand $Q$ in eigenvectors, you can find the linear change of coordinates that diagonalizes $Q$, making it explicitly $\sum\hat{x}_i^2$.)

Since you have equality constraints, the method [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Equality_constraints) is what you are doing and is perhaps organized a little more transparently.

Comment: Thanks; I'm not sure on this, since I can't represent my equality constraint in terms of Ex = d where E is a matrix.

Comment: @Zac E can be $1 \times (N+1)$. In fact, this is what you are using already (but with the wrong $d$).

Comment: I see - and actually I now I see that was the approach I had been taking all along! Unfortunately that is where I got stuck. Please, if you could, take a look at the provided code and see if that explains better - it don't know why this Ax=b appears not to be solvable? https://publiccode-zac-keskin.notebooks.azure.com/nb/notebooks/simple_quadratic_lagrangian.ipynb

Comment: I do not immediately see what is wrong. Can you compute $(\underline{\mu}-r\,\underline{1} )^T\;\underline{x}$ at the end?

Comment: Looking again I think a simple coding error may have been the problem in solving the Ax=b problem (previously I redefined A as a sympy matrix which inevitably caused problems). In which case I think this works and is a useful case-study for how to quickly solve a simple quadratic problem. If so, the only question(s) I have is: how does one include multiple lambdas in the case of multiple constraints?  I expect to stack multiple E vectors, and then...? Also will this apply the same when using slack variable to convert inequality to equality constraints?

Comment: Indeed, stack the E-vectors. See the wikipedia link. Slack variables are much harder since they have to be nonnegative. Look into interior point methods or use an off-the-shelf algorithm such as ipopt.